# Nextcloud notification on new files

Tags: nextcloud

I try to get information about new uploaded files from our Nextcloud instance. In the last years I have used two things: the filesystem of the Nextcloud and the mail mechanism. On filesystem level I can use the [inotify-tools](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools) to monitor changes on the files. Nextcloud can also send mails to users, so I can intercept and parse the mails with i.e. [maildrop](https://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/) on a local postfix instance.

Are there other possibilities? I also use the [ShareApi](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/developer_manual/client_apis/OCS/ocs-share-api.html) of Nextcloud from another server to change shares of files. Is there a similar API, which can notify my client (not Android or iOS)? Or is it necessary to implement an own Nextcloud app, which uses the [OCS hooks](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/stable/developer_manual/app/events.html#hooks) on the Nextcloud installation?

I think of an RSS feed, which I could ask with a timestamp to get the latest changes or a REST api, which I can ask for changes since a given timestamp or an implementation of [PushApi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) .

Answer (score 0):

This official https://github.com/nextcloud/notifications - This app provides a backend and frontend for the notification API available in Nextcloud. The API is used by other apps to notify users in the web UI and sync clients about various things.

You can see some examples there and create whatever notifications you wish.